# Is there a performance advantage to doing things in fewer lines of code?

Tags: c#, performance

I recently came across two ways of solving a problem and I was wondering if there's a performance difference to doing things one way or the other

Basically, the problem involved creating a method that returns true if the number of elements "n" is equal to "s", "e" is equal to "w" and the array containing these strings had to be 10 elements in length.

```
public static bool IsValidWalk(string[] walk)
  {
    if (walk.Length != 10) return false;
    var x = 0; var y = 0;
    foreach (var dir in walk)
    {
        if (dir == "n") x++;
        else if (dir == "s") x--;
        else if (dir == "e") y++;
        else if (dir == "w") y--;
    }
    return x == 0 && y == 0;
  }
```

VS.

```
public static bool IsValidWalk(string[] walk)
  {
    return walk.Count(x => x == "n") == walk.Count(x => x == "s") && walk.Count(x => x == "e") == walk.Count(x => x == "w") && walk.Length == 10;
  }
```

Comment: _"I was wondering if there's a performance difference"_ - https://ericlippert.com/performance-rant. `Count()` will iterate over the entire array. So your second sample will do that four times, where the first does it only once. But for trivial collection lengths, all of this doesn't really matter at all unless you need to do this thousands of times per second; readability matters more. Have you identified this code to be a performance bottleneck, or are you just curious? Either way, research and benchmark.

Comment: For performance, you should always *measure* things, with data that is actually relevant to your problem. 

The way it is written is mostly for humans. Compilers will do a lot of optimizations under the hood. Number of Line of codes is not correlated with performance.

Comment: Code length and code performance are not necessarily related. In your example the shorter variant is probably slower, because it iterates the array 4 times instead of 1 (unless some compiler magic happens under the hood)

Comment: Also, as you use high level framework like .NET / linq, you might need to take into account these functions as well in your big picture. (Count for instance, as I see here)

Comment: The second variant should be put as `return walk.Length == 10 && walk.Count(x => x == "n") && ...` otherwise `string[] walk = new string[1_000_000_000];` will hang your routine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's

```
if (walk.Length != 10) return false;
```

that matters **most**. When checking `10` items only either `foreach` loop or `Count` are *good enough* (technically, `Count` will be nanoseconds behind). But, your `2nd` implemention:

```
 ...
 return walk.Count(x => x == "n") == walk.Count(x => x == "s") ... && walk.Length == 10;
```

is wrong. Just see, for `walk = new string[2_000_000_000];` you first count `x` and `y` (huge loops, *2 billion* items to check) and *only then* validate `Length`. It should be

```
 // First check for length
 // Then for items of a (small, 10 items only) array
 return walk.Length == 10 
     && walk.Count(x => x == "n") == walk.Count(x => x == "s") 
     && walk.Count(x => x == "e") == walk.Count(x => x == "w");
```

first ensure that the array is short (`10` items only), then loop over it. For a *microoptimization* (let's win some nanoseconds) I suggest something like this (please, note, there's no *practical sence* in it)

```
 public static bool IsValidWalk(string[] walk)
 {
     // Since we have public method we have to validate the input - null == walk
     if (null == walk || walk.Length != 10) 
         return false;

     int x = 0; 
     int y = 0;

     // for: we don't want IEnumerator<int>
     // reverse: comparison with i >= 0 is faster then i < walk.Length
     // Magical constanct 9 instead of walk.Length - 1 makes the code a bit faster 
     for (int i = walk.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)      
     {
         string dir = walk[i];

         if (dir == "n") ++x; 
         else if (dir == "s") --x;
         else if (dir == "e") ++y;
         else if (dir == "w") --y;
     }

     // & is just a multuplication, when && will be turned into JZ (JNZ) isntructions
     return x == 0 & y == 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Both seem fairly good.

One advantage of the first one is that you immediately check for `if (walk.Length != 10) return false;` and return right away, meaning that you will not count the occurrences of a character if the main condition is not met.

However, you can achieve this by reordering you statement on the second code to have that statement first.

```c
return walk.Length == 10 && walk.Count(x => x == "n") == walk.Count(x => x == "s") && walk.Count(x => x == "e") == walk.Count(x => x == "w");
```

However, even with this information in mind, both are pretty much the same. You could only see a difference if you were dealing with a lower-level language and had to worry about how many cpu cycles an operation takes. An example of this would be `x/2` vs `x*0.5` in older machines, where division would take 1 more cycle than the alternative.

Once again, the difference is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

If you're inclined towards using shorter code, e.g. LINQ, here is an alternate idea that should perform better than your version:

```
walk.Length == 10 &&
walk.Sum(x => (x == "n" ? 1  : (x == "s" ? -1 : 0))) == 0 &&
walk.Sum(x => (x == "n" ? 1 : (x == "s" ? -1 : 0))) == 0
```